# Use a secondary h2 database for testing an API in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, testing, h2

I'm developing an API to manage a database in the company where I work, the problem is that when I have to run the different test I have to use the "real" dev database (in h2) where I have some real data.

I thought about it and what I wanted to do is create a new h2 database that could start in the testing phase, and use it to test all my Controller methods.

The problem is that I have no clue of how to achieve this in Spring Boot. If you could help me I'd be very grateful.

To sum it up:

- I have an h2 database
- I want to use a secondary h2 for testing
- How coul I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what SpringBoot's profiles are for, isn't it? Have one profile for production and another for testing. In the testing profile, say `application-testing.properties`, use H2 as your database. If you are not clear, I will post an answer explaining this.

Comment: @SreeKumar I'm totally new to Spring Boot so I'm a little bit lost, I would really appreciate it if you could explain how to do it... thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume you have 2 environments - "production" and "testing".

### Step 1: Define one configuration file for each environment

Keep one `application.properties` files for each environment. Each will contain its own settings for the database. Like this:

**Production:** `application-production.properties`

```
#Start: For MySQL 8.0 database.
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://${DB_IP}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SCHEMA}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWD}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
#End: For MySQL 8.0 database.

spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
```

**Testing:** `application-testing.properties`

```
# Start: For H2 in-memory database.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# End: For H2 in-memory database.

spring.sql.init.platform=h2
```

### Step 2: Build your application bootable JAR

There is nothing to explain here. :)

### Step 3: Pass the profile name when running the JAR

- For testing environment:
  `$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=testing <spring-boot-application-jar>`
- For production environment:
  `$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production <spring-boot-application-jar>`

The first one will use `application-testing.properties` and the second one `application-production.properties`.

There are some other factors too like default properties in `application.properties` and the specific ones in profile-based properties, etc. which you may read up on the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles).