# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I start my app, it run fine without error but after run app is crashed everytime.and show logcat Messages

> com.example.weatherapp, PID: 15301
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.weatherapp.Presentation.WeatherViewModel
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
> at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:30)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity.access$getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:28)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$onCreate$2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:58)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$onCreate$2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:48)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme_androidKt.PlatformMaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.android.kt:23)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:82)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:265)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
> at com.example.weatherapp.ui.theme.ThemeKt.WeatherAppTheme(Theme.kt:38)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:48)
> at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:47)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:402)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:248)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:247)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
> 2022-07-21 14:23:45.094 15301-15301/com.example.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:74)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3193)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3183)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown
> Source:1)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3183)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3119)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:578)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:811)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:513)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1052)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1139)
> at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20812)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2675)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8787)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
> 2022-07-21 14:23:45.095 15301-15301/com.example.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.weatherapp.Presentation.WeatherViewModel>
> has no zero argument constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
> ... 94 more
>
> ```
> I can't get rid of that error for like 7 days now... :/ I know that I posted too much code, but I really don't know how to solve it...
> ```

Thanks for getting the time to answer my question

Comment: `java.lang.Class<com.example.weatherapp.Presentation.WeatherViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693319/10134209) may be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using DI, try to incorporate
@AndroidEntryPoint to the class where are you trying to inject the dependencies