# how do i find out the reason for my error

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Firstactivity2/app/src/main/java/com/example/firstactivity2/data/database/MainHelper.kt
The root cause java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.lower.AnnotationImplementationTransformer.implementAnnotationProperties(AnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:127)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:195)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:331)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:118)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:169)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.lower.AnnotationImplementationTransformer.implementAnnotationProperties(AnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:127)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.lower.AnnotationImplementationTransformer.createAnnotationImplementation(AnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:105)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.lower.AnnotationImplementationTransformer.visitConstructorCall(AnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.lower.JvmAnnotationImplementationTransformer.visitConstructorCall(JvmAnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:48)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConstructorCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:202)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConstructorCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstructorCallImpl.accept(IrConstructorCallImpl.kt:28)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:46)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:115)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transform(IrBody.kt:39)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.transformChildren(IrField.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitFieldNew(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.accept(IrField.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrProperty.transformChildren(IrProperty.kt:58)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitProperty(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitPropertyNew(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:119)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitProperty(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:54)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitProperty(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:79)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitProperty(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrProperty.accept(IrProperty.kt:49)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitClassNew(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:111)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitClassNew(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:111)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:89)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.lower.AnnotationImplementationLowering.lower(AnnotationImplementationTransformer.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:65)
... 46 more

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693319/10134209) on how to read stack traces may help.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of **JetpackCompose** in gradle 7.2 you should add these lines in build.gradle in android block:

```
  kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.4"
    }
```

have a good day!!