# how to avoid error in android studio java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: kotlin, google-play-console

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error. The error is shown in the googleplay console. I am using Android Studio and Kotlin. There are no errors when compiling in android studio. I don't understand anything about the stack trace. Help me please. Application built with API 23 to 33.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a 
descendant of this view
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild 
(ViewGroup.java:6296)
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords 
(ViewGroup.java:6225)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.E (NestedScrollView.java:2)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onSizeChanged 
(NestedScrollView.java:3)
at android.view.View.sizeChange (View.java:23904)
at android.view.View.setFrame (View.java:23856)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23713)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.D 
(CoordinatorLayout.java:5)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.I 
(CoordinatorLayout.java:4)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout 
(CoordinatorLayout.java:8)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1891)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical 
(LinearLayout.java:1729)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1638)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout 
(DecorView.java:799)
at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6413)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:4097)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals 
(ViewRootImpl.java:3438)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2350)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run 
(ViewRootImpl.java:9194)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run 
(Choreographer.java:1231)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run 
(Choreographer.java:1239)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:899)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:832)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run 
(Choreographer.java:1214)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7884)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693319/10134209) may help in understanding stack traces.

Comment: The first two lines show where the problem is.. I have no code reference with where it's at but look for the views say at the first 5 lines of the stack trace.. it looks like you have a child without a parent. Look at your views in your code and make sure everything is lined up